# Scraping tweets with python

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping

I have a quite simple problem but I can't resolve it. I can't extract data that I want from Twitter, my code looks like this.

```
from pprint import pprint
from twitter import *

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret =''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret,consumer_key, consumer_secret ))

pythonTweets = t.search.tweets(q="#BigData")

pprint(pythonTweets)
```

Everything works like charm :) but when I run `pprint(pythonTweets)` I have a big chunk of data which is great but I can't find **twitter text** that I want to use for further data analysis and can't extract any data only I can have this big chunk of data.

I tried to use something like `pythonTweets['text']` but it doesn't work.

Comment: wouldn't `pythonTweets` be an array? So shouldn't you access them like `pythonTweets[0]['text']`? Try something along the lines of `print([tweet['text'] for tweet in pythonTweets])`

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-ea0def329683> in <module>
----> 1 print([tweet['text'] for tweet in pythonTweets])

<ipython-input-76-ea0def329683> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 print([tweet['text'] for tweet in pythonTweets])

TypeError: string indices must be integers

This is my error when I use print([tweet['text'] for tweet in pythonTweets]). If it was that simple I wouldn't ask for help :)

Comment: with 'pythonTweets[0]['text']' I have keyerror              KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-670483d9ac1d> in <module>
----> 1 pythonTweets[0]['text']

KeyError: 0

Comment: Haha you never know, always ask the dumb questions first. Could you provide a Pastebin of the `pprint(pythonTweets)` output?

Comment: Here you https://pastebin.com/jWH838Sm

Comment: Well looks like the tweet array is in `pythonTweets['statuses']`, so if I read that correctly you should be able to do `print([tweet['text'] for tweet in pythonTweets['statuses'])`

Comment: It worked thank you very much :)

Comment: Sorry but I have one more question. Could you tell me how to force the script to do not truncate the text? Here is what I mean https://pastebin.com/HJV2VuDL

Comment: Sorry for slow reply. That seems to simply be how the data is presented to you. A quick google reveals [this](https://twittercommunity.com/t/retrieve-full-tweet-when-truncated-non-retweet/75542) which seems to answer your question :)